# Importing binary structured C++ data file

Tags: import, binary, c++

I am trying to import a binary data file. It seems that BinaryReadList would be appropriate? However the data file is composed of c++ structures like this:

```
struct data1 {
    uint8_t    field1;
    uint16_t   field2;
    uint32_t   field3;
};

struct data2 {
    uint16_t   field1;
    uint16_t   field2;
    uint8_t    field3;
    uint32_t   field4;
};

struct data {
    data1  entry1;
    data2  entry2;
    data2  entry3[10];
};

int main() {

data myData[100];

}
```

Is there a way to specify the expected input format to read the data appropriately? I couldn't find a decent solution to import these data with Mathematica ?

Comment: Have you tried the third syntax format of `BinaryReadList` (`BinaryReadList["file",{type1,type2,...}]`)? If so, did it work for you or did you encounter any problems?

Comment: Thx a lot , i did overlook this option :)

Answer (score 2):

As per the comment, the third syntax format of `BinaryReadList` does what is required:

```
BinaryReadList["file",{type1,type2,...}]
```